# How to format a column 1 way, but 1 row in that column another way in R datatable (DT)

Tags: r, dt

I'm struggling with a `DT` issue where I want to format 1 column as `scientific annotation`, but some values in this column are `percentage` values as the table I am dealing with.

If I change the value in the table to `paste(n, "%", sep = ' ')` beforehand, the `rowcallback` gets stuck on non numeric value

in either scenario I can use either the `rowcallback` (see below) to format `scientific annotation` OR the other case, use `formatPercentage('columnname', 2)` to format a column in percentages, but I would like to do both to one column, and a single row therein that I need to be presented as 'n % while the rest of the column is in scientific an.

Is there a way to perform a `rowcallback` on 1 column, but exclude specific rows,

OR combine a `rowcallback` for `scientific annotation`, and format the other cells that are percentages as percentage (x %)

The `datatable` below generates the sci. an. but how to alter `cars[5,2]` to a  2 decimal % value with % symbol behind it?

```
datatable(cars/10, 
          options = list(
                 rowCallback = JS(
      "function(row, data) {",
      "    $('td:eq(2)', row).html(data[2].toExponential(1));",
      "}")
          )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have scientific annotation, you can use the function `formatC()` with the argument `format = 'e'` and `digits = 1`.

```
formatC(cars$dist[1:5] / 10, format = 'e', digits = 1)
# [1] "2.0e-01" "1.0e+00" "4.0e-01" "2.2e+00" "1.6e+00"
```

To make percentage visualisation, as `formatPercentage()` will transform all the column, you can make it yourself with `paste()`.

Then, just create a condition to tell, with `ifelse()` for instance, when using the scientific format, and when using the percentage one.

```
cars %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(. / 10)) %>% 
  mutate(Condition = 1:n()) %>% 
  mutate(dist = ifelse(Condition == 5,
                       paste(round(dist, 2), '%'),
                       formatC(dist, format = 'e', digits = 1))
  ) %>% 
  select(-Condition) %>% 
  datatable()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Formatting the column in R is not a nice option because the column type would become character and you would lost the possibility to sort the column. Here is the JavaScript way to go:

```
datatable(cars/10, 
          options = list(
            rowCallback = JS(
              "function(row, data, num, index){",
              "  if(index != 4){",
              "    $('td:eq(2)', row).html(data[2].toExponential(1));",
              "  }else{",
              "    $('td:eq(2)', row).html((100*data[2]).toFixed(2) + '%')",
              "  }",
              "}")
          )
)
```

[image]